# Existential meaning in given sentences

Tags: word-meaning, word-request

Although in dictionaries like oxford the definition is said to be :

> (formal) connected with human existence
>    (philosophy) connected with the theory of existentialism

But I've hardly found any links between above senses and below sentences :

> 1.Britain has an **existential** interest in what happens in Europe, as it always has. There is no hiding place in the Atlantic.
>
> 2.swaths of empty seats are never a good look at a sporting event. But when that event is the first Test match of the season between perennial rivals England and India, and it is England’s 1,000th Test, the sight of bare stands in the Edgbaston ground poses an **existential** question.

Side note:Second one is about criket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition from philosophy is not the only one - [see this one](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/existential) from Merriam-Webster

> of, relating to, or affirming existence

And then scroll down to read the examples of recent usage from the web, such as:

> But lately, as traditional media companies face an existential onslaught from tech players like Netflix Inc. and Alphabet Inc.

So your example sentences speak to the existence of the parties involved.

> Britain has an interest (related to its very existence) in what happens in Europe...
>
> ... the sight of bare stands in the Edgbaston ground poses a question (about the existence of test cricket).

Comment: So if I have got it right,first one should translate into: britain has an interest in why they have interest in what happens in Europe . Am I right?

Comment: @Abbas Britain has an interest in what happens in Europe, because it affects Britain's existence.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. of or relating to existence, esp human existence

An existential interest or crisis is an interest or crisis affecting one's existence.

[Existential](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/existential)